# How to create joined string of all text under span classes using XPATH

Tags: html, r, xpath

I'm unable to properly collect the data from the span classes I am looking for. I want to create a list (or really, a combined string) of all of the text from all of these span classes.

The classes I'm looking at are embedded under other classes, but it seems from the output I'm currently getting, that my code is able to location the number of occurrences of the class, and just not extract the text.

```
<div class="author-group" id="author-group">
    <a class="author size-m workspace-trigger" name="bau2" href="#!">
        <span class="content">
            <span class="text given-name">Jane</span>
            <span class="text surname">Doe</span>
            <span class="author-ref" id="baff1">
    <sup>a</sup></span></span></a>
```

They're all under their own  as shown above, and all of them are under the same .

From this, I would want to be able to get Jane Doe. This class repeats multiple times, and the end goal is to get "Jane Doe; Sam Smith; Joe Gregory." This is my relevant code thus far.

```
doc <- read_html(x) 
just_scripts <- html_nodes(doc, "script") %>% html_text()
sur_author = html_nodes(doc, xpath = '//span[@class="text surname"]/text()') %>% 
    html_attr('content')
given_author = html_nodes(doc, xpath = '//span[@class="text given-name"]/text()') %>% 
    html_attr('content')
Given_Author <- paste(given_author, collapse=" ; ")
Sur_Author <- paste(sur_author, collapse=" ; ")
```

Outside of this function, I have the code writing into an excel spreadsheet and I'm getting results like this:
NA ; NA ; NA

It seems to be able to determine how many authors there are, and properly create a space for each, yet it cannot extract the actual text of the authors names into my file.

Comment: Rather than `html_attr('content')`, use `html_text()`. These nodes don't seem to have an attribute named "content".

Comment: Thank you! This worked!